# How to add multiple values to a property in neo4j

Tags: java, neo4j

I am new to neo4j and trying to add multiple values to a property of a node.How to do it?

```
 create (e:Employee{name:"Sam",languages:["C","C#"]})
```

Tried this but didn't find any proper way to add multiple values to an attribute.

Comment: your query should work except the missing " after the C# but I guess it is a typo, what do you want more exactly ?

Comment: how do i add values to the property languages and later how will query the same using CYPHER.Curently it is taken just as a string i guess,

Comment: The syntax seems to work perfectly fine. The question isn't quite clear and adds to and already existing heap of questions on this topic in SO. Would suggest that the question be merged with any similar questions for clarity to readers

Answer (score 1):

Properties cannot have object values. If you're looking to store multiple properties on `language`, and those properties all belong to the language and not any other entity, then you should model Language as a node. You can store properties on the relationship between the employee and language as well if required.

Then you'll end up with something like this:

```
create (l:Language {name:"C", otherProperty:"property value"})
create (e:Employee {name:"Sam"})
create (e)-[:SPEAKS {level:"Fluent"}]->(l)
```

Answer (score 1):

In fact, you can have array values in properties. You should be able to create them like:

```
CREATE (n:Node { color: ['Red', 'Blue']})
RETURN n
```

In your case:

```
CREATE (e:Employee { name:"Sam",languages: ["C", "C#"]})
RETURN e
```

is working perfectly fine (you can check it in http://console.neo4j.org/)

Keep in mind that all values in the array must be of the same type, only Strings, or Integers, etc. You can find more info here -> http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/rest-api-property-values.html

However that's not the best approach for that particular example given that `C` and `C#` are languages that `Sam` knows, you should have them as different nodes pointed by `Sam` through some kind of `Knows` relationship.