# How to add multiple values to existing nodes with Cypher in Neo4J

Tags: csv, neo4j, cypher, graph-databases

I'm trying to load some data in Neo4J. I have a `Person` node which is already setup. Now, this node needs to have an `email` property which should be an array(or collection). Basically, the `email` property needs to have multiple values, like -

```
email: ["abc@xyz.com", "abc@foo.com"]
```

I've come across similar questions here but all of the answers indicate to setting multiple property values **at the time the node itself is created**. Like this query from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30842029/how-to-add-multiple-values-to-a-property-in-neo4j) answer -

```
CREATE (e:Employee { name:"Sam",languages: ["C", "C#"]})
RETURN e
```

But the problem in my case is that `Person` node *is already created*, and I need to set the `email` property on it now.

This is a small subset of the data I have to load -

```
 Personid|email 
933|Mahinda933@hotmail.com 
933|Mahinda933@yahoo.com
933|Mahinda933@zoho.com 
1129|Carmen1129@gmail.com
1129|Carmen1129@gmx.com 
1129|Carmen1129@yahoo.com
4194|Ho.Chi4194@gmail.com 
4194|Ho.Chi4194@gmx.com
```

Also, the data is coming from a CSV file with thousands of rows, so my query needs to be generic, I can't set the properties for each individual `Person` node.

When I was testing out the creation of the email property with this subset, my first attempt was this -

```
 MATCH (n:TESTPERSON{id:933})
 SET n.email = "Mahinda933@hotmail.com"
 RETURN n

 MATCH (n:TESTPERSON{id:933})
 SET n.email = "Mahinda933@yahoo.com"
 RETURN n
```

As I was thinking, this just overwrites the `email` property to the value in the most recent query.

After looking at the answers here and on the Cypher docs, I found out that Neo4J allows you to set an array/collection (multiple values of the same type) as a property value, and then I tried this -

```
 // CREATE test node
 CREATE (n:TESTPERSON{id:933})
 RETURN n

 // at this time, this node does not have any `email` property, so setup 
 // email as an array with one string value
 MATCH (n:TESTPERSON{id:933})
 SET n.email = ["Mahinda933@hotmail.com"]
 RETURN n


 // Now, using +=, I can append to the array of strings
 MATCH (n:TESTPERSON{id:933})
 SET n.email = n.email + "Mahinda933@yahoo.com"
 RETURN n

 // add a third value to array
 MATCH (n:TESTPERSON{id:933})
 SET n.email = n.email + "Mahinda933@zoho.com"
 RETURN n
```

Here's the result - [image]

As you can see, the `email` property now has multiple values.

But the problem is that since my CSV file has thousands of rows, I need a generic query to do this.

I thought of using a `CASE` statement as per the documentation [here](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/syntax/expressions/), and tried this -

```
MATCH (n:TESTPERSON {id:933}) 
CASE 
WHEN n.email IS NULL THEN SET n.email = [ "Mahinda933@hotmail.com"] 
ELSE SET n.email = n.email + "Mahinda933@yahoo.com" 
RETURN n
```

But this just throws the error - `mismatched input CASE expecting ;`.

I was hoping I could use this query as a generic way for my CSV file like this -

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'FILEURL' AS line FIELDTERMINATOR `|`
MATCH (n:TESTPERSON {id:toInt(line.Personid)}) 
CASE 
WHEN n.email IS NULL THEN SET n.email = [line.email] 
ELSE SET n.email = n.email + line.email
```

But I don't even know if this would work, even if the `CASE` error is fixed.

I'm really stumped, and would appreciate any help. Thank You.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use COALESCE() to use a default value in case the value you're trying to get is null. You might use it like this:

`...
SET n.email = COALESCE(n.email, []) + "Mahinda933@yahoo.com"
...`

Whenever you're setting an array of values as a node property, it's a good idea to consider whether you might instead model these as separate nodes with relationships to the original node.

In this case, :Email nodes with some relationship to your :TESTPERSON nodes, with one :Email node per email, and multiple relationships from :TESTPERSON to multiple :Emails.

An advantage here is you'd be able to support uniqueness constraints, if you want to ensure there's only one :Email in the system, and you would be able to quickly look up a person by their email if you have an index or unique constraint, as the query would use the index to lookup the :Email and from there it's only one relationship traversal to the owner of the email.

When you have values in a collection on a node, you can't use an index lookup to a value in the collection, so your current model won't be able to quickly lookup a person by their email.

Comment: Thank You! This worked perfectly. Here's the query I executed - `LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "fileURL" AS line
FIELDTERMINATOR '|'
MATCH (n:TESTPERSON {id: toInt(line.Personid)}) 
SET n.email = COALESCE(n.email, []) + line.email`

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution using `MERGE`:

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'file:///p.csv' AS line FIELDTERMINATOR '|'
MERGE (p:Person {id:toInteger(line.Personid)})
ON CREATE SET p.mail = line.email
ON MATCH SET p.mail = p.mail + '-' + line.email
```

The `MERGE` command take care of the duplicate nodes, and then we're setting the properties only when the node is created with `ON CREATE SET`, and when the node is already in the database (i.e. `ON MATCH SET`), we're going to add the email address to the property.

Hope that helps.

This is my result in Neo4j:
[image]

Comment: Hi, Thank You for the answer!! My code already has the `Person` node setup, so I think this line will not be executed at all - `ON CREATE SET p.mail = line.email`. That means `p.mail` will be `null` and when it reaches the `ON MATCH SET` clause, the code `ON MATCH SET p.mail = p.mail + '-' + line.email` will result in `null` because at this point `p.mail` is still `null`, and adding anything to `null` will return `null`.
Also, in the code in your screenshot, `email` is a string property with strings concatenated using `-`, while I need `email` to be an array of strings, instead. Thoughts?

Comment: I see the problem now, thanks! I think you can implement the @InverseFalcon answer in my code and should fix the problem!

Answer (score 0):

A quick workaraound is to load your data in two steps

1/ LOAD CSV, create node with empty array property

2/LOAD CSV again, set emails +=

3/ Optionnal, depending on your data for each node, remove doubles in the array (do it with a custom procedure).

Should do it. I also am not very happy with the CASE syntax

Comment: Thank You! I was thinking of doing this way, but turns out you can do it in one pass with `COALESCE`.

Comment: I tend to forget coalesce. It is a better answer.